# Android Softkeyboard - "Prev" and "Next" not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an Activity that contains only a `LinearLayout` and a `WebView` as a child. The `WebView` only displays a form to submit with the user data (**I don't have control over the content of this form**). When I press on a field inside the `WebView` the softkeyboard is displayed with the "Go" button at the bottom and when I long-press the "Go" button a popup button with the label "Next" appears at the top, however when I press "next" nothing happens.

[image]

**So my question is how to catch the event of the "Next" button in this scenario as I'm using a form with text fields?** 
I would like to set the behavior of the "Next" button as a tab key to navigate to the next text field.